# AutoCompleteTextView getSelectedItemPosition

Tags: android, adapter, autocompletetextview

I need to identify which item from adapter was selected by user (when dropdown suggestions appear).

If user selects item, i want to be able to obtain either:

- **position if selected item** - **but i need position in respect to all items in adapter**.
- some kind of **unique identifier of selected item**
- if user doesnt select any of my suggestions and types his own text, i will just receive null or -1 or something.

Is this possible to do with AutoCompleteTextView?

Example:

I have standard ArrayAdapter for my AutoCompleteTextView, with following items:

```
{"one","one2","two","two2", "three", "three2"}
```

User types in

> thr

he is suggested 2 options:

> three, three2

Then he selects "three2".
When OnItemSelected is fired, "position" parameter is set to 1, because there were just 2 suggestions.

However, what i wanted is to get position of 5 because my adapter has total of 6 items.

Answer (score 1):

here is What i have Done for the Simillar Problem.

i have Use adapter to set the Autocomplete textview.

here is my **PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter.java** file

```
package com.inukshk.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;

import com.inukshk.CreateInukshk.CreateInukshk;

public class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements
        Filterable {
    private ArrayList<String> resultList;

    public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.

                    resultList = CreateInukshk.autocomplete(constraint
                            .toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                    FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
}
```

here i have used **resultList = CreateInukshk.autocomplete(constraint
                                .toString());** which is my method that will return the arraylist i want to display.

and Finally here is my code in main java file where i have intialized our AutoCompleteTextview.

Inside OnCreate();

```
autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editloc);
        autoCompView.setAdapter(new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_item));
        // autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(CreateInukshk.this);

        autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            // here you can get value of arg2 as your position while selecting value.
                // Place = autoCompView.getText().toString();
                new AsyncGetAutoPlace().execute(autoCompView.getText()
                        .toString().trim());
            }
        });
```

instead of   **new AsyncGetAutoPlace().execute(autoCompView.getText()
                        .toString().trim());** you can add your code whatever you want to do.

Hope it would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set an [OnItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html)

Comment: yes i tried it. Reason it doesnt work for me is because it only returns selected position with respect to currently suggested items. It means, if user is suggested 2 items, and selects first, it returns 0 as a position, while it should return for example 24, because there are 40 items in adapter.

Comment: there must be something wrong inside your adapter implementation. My Adapters have the same amount of items than the amount suggested. Have you confirmed, that if your autocomplete will suggest 2 items, that the getCount() from Adapter is returning i.e. 40? If so, please post relevant parts of your Adapter

Answer (score 0):

```
String str_numbers = your_autocompletetext_view.gettext();
int exact_postion;

// here your_List is a list which you have assigned for your_autocompletetext_view
for(int i0; i<your_List.size();i++)
{

    if(str_numbers.equals(your_List.get(i).toString))
     {
       exact_postion=i; // this is your exact position
        break;
  }     
}
```